# How to merge cropped images back to original image?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have an image of size 10980x10980 and I cropped this image by using python script into 256x256 size. the script I used for cropping is :

```
from PIL import Image

  infile = 'Amritsar_T43SDR.tif'
  chopsize = 256

   img = Image.open(infile)
    width, height = img.size

     for x0 in range(0, width, chopsize):
          for y0 in range(0, height, chopsize):
          box = (x0, y0,
                x0+chopsize if x0+chopsize <  width else  width - 1,
                y0+chopsize if y0+chopsize < height else height - 1)
          print('%s %s' % (infile, box))
          img.crop(box).save('Train.%s.x%03d.y%03d.tif' % (infile.replace('.tif',''), x0, y0))
```

image is successfully cropped as per given dimension in 1855 images (the majority of image file size is 193K but some image of size 171Kb generated)

now I want to roll back the whole procedure i.e. using cropped images, merging all tiles back to the original image. we found a function rollback which is as follows

```
def roll(image, delta):
    x0, y0 = img.size

delta = delta % xsize
if delta == 0: return image

part1 = image.crop((0, 0, delta, y0))
part2 = image.crop((delta, 0, x0, y0))
image.paste(part1, (x0-delta, 0, x0, y0))
image.paste(part2, (0, 0, x0-delta, y0))

return image
```

It doesn't catch the original dimensions
alternatively, we used ImageMajik program and issued the command as

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 43x85 Train*.tif new_amritsar.tif
```

resultantly it merges the images but not in the real order

Please suggest me the solution

regards
Yasir

[list of cropped images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcM4m.jpg)

[list of cropped images with different size and scale as 10980 x 10980 were not split exactly 256 x 356](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zvgg.png)

Comment: What OS are you using please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows, you may have difficulty with my other answer, so here is a Python-based answer.

Again, I would suggest you change your file naming to accommodate zero-padding to a length of 5 digits. You can then get a list of all the y-offsets by looking at files with `x00000` in their names, and a list of all the x-offsets by looking at all the files with `y00000` in their name.

That might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import glob

# Generate a list of all the Y offsets by looking at all the Train*x00000*tif filenames
yoffsets = []
for f in glob.glob("Train*x00000*tif"):
    # Look for a `y` followed by 5 digits
    yoffsets.append(int(re.findall(r'y(\d{5})', f)[0]))

# Generate a list of all the X offsets by looking at all the Train*y00000*tif filenames
xoffsets = []
for f in glob.glob("Train*y00000*tif"):
    # Look for an `x` followed by 5 digits
    xoffsets.append(int(re.findall(r'x(\d{5})', f)[0]))

# Generate filenames in order
for y in sorted(yoffsets):
   ypad = str(y).zfill(5)
   for x in sorted(xoffsets):
      xpad = str(x).zfill(5)
      print(f"Train...y{ypad}.x{xpad}.tif")
```

Now you can either print the filenames to a file and start **ImageMagick** `montage` as before, or you can create a big empty canvas, open the files one at a time inside my final `for` loop and paste each one at the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try this. First change your filenaming a little bit to accommodate a larger number of tiles:

```
img.crop(box).save('Train.%s.y%05d.x%05d.tif' % (infile.replace('.tif',''), y0, x0))
```

Now your `x` and `y` coordinates should be reversed for easier sorting and zero-padded to 5 places rather than 3.

Then you should be able to get a list of files in the correct order with:

```
ls Train.Amritsar_T43SDR*tif | sort -n > files.txt
```

And then montage them with:

```
magick montage -geometry +0+0 -tile 43x @files.txt result.tif
```

Or, if you want an equivalent one-liner:

```
ls Train.Amritsar_T43SDR*tif | sort -n | magick montage -geometry +0+0 -tile 43x @- result.tif
```

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, re-assemble, jigsaw, ImageMagick, montage.